# SQLite return records that match a specifc set of records in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that has a one-to-many relationship to another table. I want the records from the first table that match a specific set in the second table.

```
CREATE TABLE A (aId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE B (bId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, aId INTEGER, c INTEGER);

INSERT INTO A (aId) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO A (aId) VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO B (bId, aId, c) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO B (bId, aId, c) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO B (bId, aId, c) VALUES (3, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO B (bId, aId, c) VALUES (4, 2, 3);
```

For example, I was aId Where c is 1 and 2. so aId = 1. I don't want it to return aId 2 because while it matches c = 2 it doesn't have c = 1.

```
SELECT aId FROM B WHERE c IN(1,2);
```

Gives me 1,1,2. Is there something similar that matches all elements rather than any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many items are in the IN clause for C,

```
SELECT aID FROM B WHERE C IN(1,2) GROUP BY aID HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

where the `COUNT(*)` is equal to the number of elements in the `IN`. If the filter is more complicated, we’ll need another approach.

Comment: Thanks. This gives what I want, but what do you mean, if the filter is more complicated. What situations would this not work?

Comment: If you don't know in advance how many elements are in the `IN` clause.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem then. I can just count them as I build the query in my program. Thanks again.